# Ruby on rails controller copy does not autorize user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller, redmine

Disclaimer: I'm completely new to ruby..

I've copied  [this controller](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/2.6-stable/app/controllers/timelog_controller.rb) with the name `timelog_estimates_controller.rb`, changed the class name to `TimelogEstimatesController` created different route but the page gives me "403 forbidden"

When I use the original TimelogController it works perfectly fine.
I suppose there is something I've missed.

Comment: The link you published is wrong.

Comment: Why is it supposed to be wrong? I'm currently usin RoR 2.6

Comment: what do you mean "created different route"

Comment: That means the original url was 
http://127.0.0.1/redmine/issues/1/time_entries 
And I added another route 
http://127.0.0.1/redmine/issues/1/time_entries_estimates
The original controller `TimeEntries` works fine with the second route `time_entries_estimates`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redmine uses declarative permissioning. When you created a new controller, it and its actions are missing from permissions definition and therefore inaccessible.

To fix that you need to include your new controller's relevant actions into permissions definitions. [This is the location in `lib/redmine.rb`](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/2.6-stable/lib/redmine.rb#L128-L134) you probably need to modify. Copied here for clarity:

```
  map.project_module :time_tracking do |map|
    map.permission :log_time, {:timelog => [:new, :create]}, :require => :loggedin
    map.permission :view_time_entries, {:timelog => [:index, :report, :show]}, :read => true
    map.permission :edit_time_entries, {:timelog => [:edit, :update, :destroy, :bulk_edit, :bulk_update]}, :require => :member
    map.permission :edit_own_time_entries, {:timelog => [:edit, :update, :destroy,:bulk_edit, :bulk_update]}, :require => :loggedin
    map.permission :manage_project_activities, {:project_enumerations => [:update, :destroy]}, :require => :member
  end
```

You should add something like this inside this block:

```
    map.permission :view_time_estimates, {:timelog_estimates => [:index, :report, :show]}, :read => true
    map.permission :edit_time_estimates, {:timelog_estimates => [:edit, :update, :destroy, :bulk_edit, :bulk_update]}, :require => :member
    map.permission :edit_own_time_estimates, {:timelog_estimates => [:edit, :update, :destroy,:bulk_edit, :bulk_update]}, :require => :loggedin
```

The authorization works through this call in your controller:

```
before_filter :authorize_global, :only => [:new, :create, :index, :report]
```

If you follow `authorize_global` implementation, you will [find this](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/2.6-stable/app/controllers/application_controller.rb#L269-L281):

```
  # Authorize the user for the requested action
  def authorize(ctrl = params[:controller], action = params[:action], global = false)
    allowed = User.current.allowed_to?({:controller => ctrl, :action => action}, @project || @projects, :global => global)
    if allowed
      true
    else
      if @project && @project.archived?
        render_403 :message => :notice_not_authorized_archived_project
      else
        deny_access
      end
    end
  end
```

The `render_403` line is the reason you're getting the error.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance,  I don't quite understand what exactly shold I do\write in `project_module :time_tracking` ?

Comment: I've added the lines you likely need.

Comment: Yeah, I've got it already. I figured out that it would much be preferable to use separate plugin with copied controllers. Unless your answer fits my question but it is a hardcode way. Anyway, thanx a lot!